Preserving exact path to object that matches query string
I have modal in a React app that renders a list of items with a list of nested values and a search bar. When the user types into the search bar, I need to be able to match that input to an item in the list and show the exact path to that match.
For example, my data looks like:
const dataList = [
  {
    label: 'Foo',
    value: 'foo',
    subItems: [
      {
        label: 'Sub bar 1',
        value: 'sub_bar_1',
        subItems: [
          { label: 'Nested baz 1', value: 'nested_baz_1' },
          { label: 'Nested baz 2', value: 'nested_baz_2' },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Sub bar 2',
        value: 'sub_bar_2',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Bar',
    value: 'bar',
    subItems: [],
  },
];

And given the query string, Nested baz 2, I'd expect the output to be:
const filteredList = [{
   label: 'Foo',
   value: 'foo',
   subItems: [
     {
       label: 'Sub bar 1',
       value: 'sub_bar_1',
       subItems: [
         { label: 'Nested baz 2', value: 'nested_baz_2' },
       ],
     },
  ],
}];


I've tried multiple iterations of a recursive function and old-school for loops but nothing can give me the exact path to the object that matches my query string.
Is there anything I can change in this current implementation to get the desired output?
 const filterItems = (
   options: Option[],
   query: string
 ): Option[] => {
   return options.filter((option) => {
     if (option.label.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
       return true;
     }
     if (option.subItems) {
       return filterItems(option.subItems, query).length > 0;
     }
     return false;
   });
 };

 const filteredItems = useMemo(() => {
   return filterItems(options, query);
 }, [options, query]);

[EDIT]: update so that recursive call was calling the right function

You can achieve this with the below
const filterDataList = (dataList, searchTerm) => {
return dataList
.map(item => {
  if (item.label.includes(searchTerm)) {
    return item;
  }

  if (item.subItems && item.subItems.length > 0) {
    const filteredSubItems = filterDataList(item.subItems, searchTerm);

    if (filteredSubItems.length > 0) {
      return { ...item, subItems: filteredSubItems };
    }
  }

  return null;
})
.filter(item => item !== null);
}
 const searchTerm = 'Nested baz 2';
 const filteredList = filterDataList(dataList, searchTerm);


The problem with your implementation is that you lose the filtering you have applied here:
return filterCategories(option.subItems, query).length > 0;

The filtered array is not retained: only the length serves to return false/true, but when it is true, you still have all the subItems. You need to create new objects when the subItems property is going to get a reduced array.
You could combine map with filter, where you map either a new object with reduced subItems, or undefined. Chain a filter call to only retain the objects:
const filterItems = (
           options: Option[],
           query: string
        ): Option[] => {
    return options.map((option: Option) => {
        if (option.label.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) {
            return option;
        }
        if (option.subItems) {
            const subItems = filterItems(option.subItems, query);
            if (subItems.length > 0) return { ...option, subItems };
        }
    }).filter(Boolean);
};

